# NetSuite : ADV PDF Template toFixed

Tags: html, netsuite

Does anyone here knows how to have to decimal places in html code?

`<#assign unitprice = item.itemunitprice/>`
`<td border-bottom="0" border-right="1" border-top="1" align="right">${unitprice}</td>`

There times that the returning value is whole number {10,000} or with one (1) decimal place {10,000.8}.
Is there a way that the displaying value would become {10,000.00} or {10,000.80}.
Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
${unitprice?string.currency}
```

Comment: Already tried this one but returns an error.

   `For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> unitprice?string [in template "template" at line 190, column 79]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${unitprice?string.currency} [in template "template" at line 190, column 77]
----`

Comment: Weird, string.currency is the same thing I use.  Are you validating that the data is good before trying to print it out?

Comment: @Saizou I've run into this error a lot recently. I've spent hours trying to "fix" it. This occurs because NetSuite's WYSWYG editor it trying to validate everything. For some reason it's not seeing the field types for what they really are. Try and save your template anyway, with the error. Then go and test the print. I'm guessing it will work just fine, unless there are other errors.

Answer (score 0):

I also use ?string.currency. Also, to access price of a sales order I usually use item.amount, not sure if that would change anything.